# Adding items to subment 'New' in eclipse cnf

Tags: eclipse-rcp, cnf

I am using eclipse CNF. When I place a right click in the project or folder for CNF, I see a pop up menu which contains an option "New" and that also contains submenu. How do i add an item to that submenu?

[image: Eclipse CNF 'New' Submenu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems i have figured out the way to do it :) :)

following link might help me as well as others searching for the same kind of solution...

http://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2010/04/04/writing-an-eclipse-plug-in-part-20-re turn-of-the-popup-menu-for-an-empty-navigator/